# Google sheets conditional formatting of lowest n

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I keep sheets with scores for players, and the 10 lowest scores are counting.
What I would like to do is to color the 10 first lowest scores in light green.
The last highest number of those 10 in darker green. (It's the score to beat in order to improve your total score) And the lowest score in yellow.

I guess it is easier to explain with an example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BSGfpzmaibsR4dxHqFgmYmJq7RtyAEV8uRCB0S3Fa4A/edit?usp=sharing

Feel free to copy your own set and try out:)
[image]

Comment: Does it need to be totally contained within the conditional formatting formula?

Comment: No, can use any means :)

Comment: Can you share the formula you're using? We can't see it in the sheet you've given us access to without requesting edit access.

Comment: I have changed to edit access :)
And given you your own bit to try out on, I have started to test out your solution, but will stay away from your bit :)

Comment: Maybe easier to solve with scripts?

Comment: The problem is you've got the same value multiple times in the 10 games. So you need to know which one is the last. I think a script is the way to go here as Ove points out.. Is that an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to get Rank without ties, and this would give you Rank without ties:

```
=RANK(B2,$B2:2,1)+COUNTIF($B2:B2,B2)-1
```

With correct rank it's easy to add custom formatting for the highest of the 10 lowest:

```
=RANK(B2,$B2:2,1)+COUNTIF($B2:B2,B2)-1=10
```

Since it works on a range, B2 in the formula will be substituted for each cell in the range.

So the problematic cell O4 will give:

```
RANK(O2,$B2:2,1) equals 10
COUNTIF($B2:O2,O2) equals 2
so
RANK(B2,$B2:2,1)+COUNTIF($B2:B2,B2)-1 equals 11 ie it will not be colored
```

Had to add an extra condition to color the highest scores for players with less than 10 scores.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can get quickly is with 3 rules:

1: Lowest:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:Q2),"SELECT Col1 ORDER BY Col1 DESC LIMIT 10"),"SELECT MIN(Col1) LABEL MIN(Col1) ''")
```

2: Highest:

```
=MAX(B2:Q2)
```

3: Then a between:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:Q2),"SELECT Col1 ORDER BY Col1 DESC LIMIT 10"),"SELECT MIN(Col1) LABEL MIN(Col1) ''")+1
```

&

```
=MAX(B2:Q2)-1
```

Comment: 1: Colors everything up to the last non empty cell  
2: It's the max of the 10 lowest, not the max of the row  
3: For Plyr 4 the latest 43 score should not be light green or dark green

Comment: I think coloring of the lowest is solved by: =RANK(B2,$B2:2,1)=1

But the tricky part is when there is a tie on the 10th score like for player 3 and 4

Comment: So it's lowest and highest for all players for all games?